# Collect data over a period

Tags: php, twitter

I want to collect data of a particular keyword for the last seven days without user authentication on twitter. The problem is that the result set for one day itself was more than 3000. This quickly blocks my app due to rate limitation. I need a work around this. In fact I don't need the data, I just need the count for each day ( probably this is not possible). Could you please advise me to get over the same. I am using search api, and I am open to use any api.

One more question: Is it possible to collect the public posts at regular intervals ( all posts, without a query term). If this is possible then I can save them in my database and perform the search on the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/164291

Comment: @todofixthis: Thank you for the formatting tips :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the [streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis). You can think of it as setting a keyword and opening a firehose where you will receive tweets containing your keyword until you close the firehose connection. The streaming API is designed for persistent connections, tracking a limited number of keywords. You login with basically a default user.

This [140 PHP Development Framework](http://140dev.com/free-twitter-api-source-code-library/) is a great help in working with the Twitter streaming API in PHP.

Resources:

- Twitter Streaming API Information -
  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis
- 140 Twitter Streaming API Framework -
  http://140dev.com/free-twitter-api-source-code-library/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Will this allow to receive the tweets of last 7 days? or will it only allow access to tweets from then on?

Comment: then on starting from when you open the socket.

Comment: Once again thankyou for your reply. But this does not my problem. The problem with this is that, I have to wait seven days for a particular keyword. In my case, the keyword may change any moment, so this approach is not possible

Comment: hmm another approach you can take is querying old tweets. You have two options, `since` & `until` [search operator](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search). Or also look into [SnapBird](https://github.com/saurabhagarwal/snapbird) for circumventing search limitations

Comment: I have done this. But the problem is that ( as mentioned above) there are 1000's of tweet per day. Due to api restrictions, I am only getting one or two days tweet :(

Comment: you looked at the snapbird api?

Comment: @Chamliyan That also will not solve the problem. It may help me to obtain a tweet back in history. But what I want is the number of tweets with that query for the last seven days. I just want the number (if tweets are there it will be more helpful)

Comment: well those are your three options. It seems like the best approach is streaming for what your describing. You just count what came into the bucket over seven days for the keyword(s).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15748/discussion-between-knightrider-and-chamilyan)